# Rebuilding old HDD

Tags: hard-drive, partition, disk-space, hdd

My mac is turning 5 years now, it runs already long on SDD and old HDD is in  an optibay. But HDD is a stock one and is turning 5 years as well. It's working ok, but tests with Disk warrior, Tech Tool and DriveDx indicated 2 bad blocks, besides I had issues with a couple of big files. And as I assume there can appear more.
As far as I know, HDDs have a special reserved space, that gets used, when bad blocks are found. So the question is can this reserved space be extended? If yes, then what software would you recommend for that?

Comment: Be sure to save the magnets when you decommission the drive. They're strong and useful for a variety of purposes. Although brittle, you can knock them off their metal holders intact with one well placed blow with a hammer wood chisel.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger I've taken apart an old hdd before, but I hope I won't need to do this in 2-3 years with this one

Answer (score 1):

> So the question is can this reserved space be extended?

No, it cannot.

Hard disk failures tend to be catastrophic in nature -- if enough sectors have failed that you have exhausted the built-in reserve and you are seeing "issues with a couple of big files", your hard disk is likely in the process of failing, and no amount of additional spare space will save it.

You need to discontinue all use of this drive until you can back it up and replace it. Any further use is likely to result in data loss.

Comment: I guess that relocated bad block count will increase faster over time, but isn't it possible to extend hhd's life for say a couple of months?

Comment: Not reliably. Hard drive failures of this type tend to be the result of mechanical processes within the drive, e.g. fine particulate material inside the disk causing damage to the platter surface. The longer the drive runs, the worse the damage will get. No amount of software changes will slow or stop this process.

Comment: I understand, though it may be a temporary solution. I've found service software that allows working with bad sectors, like Victoria, but they all run on Windows and doesn't support HFS.